# Why do the execute bits need to be set?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

I have a simple python script that is writing data to a file in a log folder. The script is in /var/lib/cgi-bin and the log folder is in /var/lib/cgi-bin/logs. As the files in cgi-bin are executed by Apache or by me from the command line, the execute bits are set for both cgi-bin and files in cgi-bin.

However, when I try setting 666 on the cgi-bin/logs folder, the python script fails when I attempt to open a new log file to store data.  If I set the permissions on cgi-bin/logs to 776, the script executes both from the command line and when a browser executes a file in cgi-bin.

Why does a folder that will only contain data need the execute bit set? Is it due to being inside a folder that must have the execute bits set?

Comment: The execute bit has a different meaning on folders, since you can't _execute_ a folder. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: Thanks @tkausl. I was thinking that the permission bits of a folder were inherited by the files when they're created. I didn't know the setfacl command handled file permission inheritance.

Comment: An answer is provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that a folder's permissions were inherited by the folder's contents which is incorrect.

Tkausl pointed out that execute permission on a folder doesn't mean the same thing that execute permission means on a file.  For a folder, execute permission means the folder's contents may be viewed by the owner, group and/or all.

Linux uses a specific command, setfacl, to handle default file permissions.